# How can I clean and prepare a git repo that I'd like to make public?

Tags: git

I'm working on a project that I'd like to eventually make public on a site like GitHub or BitBucket.

However, my local repository for the project currently only has a `master` branch that contains nothing but experimental commits that are only intended to be seen by me. These commits contain things like messy code, irrelevant files, slapdash comments meant only to be read by myself, and so on.

Once the experimental part of the project is over, my intention is to clean everything up: make my code nice and organized, remove any cruft, and basically get it in a state where it's ready to be shared. However, I don't want to split apart my git repository or remove any of the history I've built up so far.

What are some ways I can keep using this git repo and only publish commits that contain cleaned up code? Basically there will eventually be a commit that I want to be the first public commit, and after that point all future commits will be public as well.

Comment: You can construct, store, fetch, mix, match and push any histories you want into any repositories you control. Construct the history you want to publish, push it to a(ny) repo, advertise whatever url will reach that repo, done.  Constructing new histories from old ones is basically what every command other than `add`, `commit`, `branch` and `tag` are for, look at the history you have, imagine the history you want, and hit the docs.  Cherrypick, rebase, filter-branch, reset, the `--patch` option (and many other handy ones) on add and checkout and  reset and more... ask about something specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the current `master`-branch is just for you and you don't want to publish it I would go following way:

- cleanup your working directory to the state you want to publish and test
- commit the changes
- rename `master` to a proper name like `private-develop` via `git branch -M private-develop`
- create a new `master` branch via `git checkout -b master`
- interactive rebase and squash all commits from the 2nd commit upwards together via `git rebase -i <FIRSTCOMMIT>`
- push the new `master` branch to the remote server via `git push origin master`